# Ubuntu Software Center doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-software

After fixing `/dev/sda` in busybox and boot my computer, I'm trying to run Ubuntu Software. It is loaded, but it didn't open. Now I have two software applications, Ubuntu Software which I can't open and Software.

[image: image1]

Comment: But it didn't the problem instead it installs 'Software' which is similar to Ubuntu Software Center. I want to fix the Ubuntu Software Center. Not to Install another store. Thank you for answering my question. May be I missing something.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: So, now I have two software. Ubuntu Software which I can't open and Software which I accidentally download while I fixing the Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Software Centers in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1245872). The orange shopping basket icon is for Ubuntu Software.