# Two Software Centers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center, 20.04, gnome-software

I have two software centers in Ubuntu, but I am sure there should be one: 
[image: Image1]

And Moreover both have the source "ubuntu focal-main". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you install multiple desktop environments then this thing happens.

Gnome supports gnome software centre, but the distro maker changes it a bit and introduces it as another software centre. So if you do `sudo apt install gnome-software` then the default gnome software centre is installed along side the one shipped by the manufacturer.

Comment: accept the answer if it solves your problem satisfactorily. click the tick mark besides my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you by chance installed some other desktop environment like xubuntu? This is the gnome software center. Ubuntu’s one is a front end made by Canonical. Nothing to worry about here.

Comment: No , I never installed any other desktop environment other than ubuntu .